# Storing large (e.g. image/movie) files in Core Data on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data

Looking at the Apple iPhone Core Data Recipes sample app, they store image files in core data objects, which is not something I would normally think would be wise. Now I'm going to be also storing captured video on the 3GS. The question is: is it wise to store images, and then furthermore, movies, in Core Data on the iPhone?

In addition there is the addition of loading into memory. Apparently the design used in Recipes (i.e., storing the image in a separate model) allows Core Data to do "faulting" (which sounds like it means lazy loading), but I'm not sure if that's really true.

Looking here: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW5 it seems that the generic Cocoa advice is to use separate files....

Comment: the link is not valid anymore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends. CoreData is more than capable of storing large blobs with good performance. The big gotchas are:

1. If those blobs are properties of entities that might not always be faulted in you need to be careful to make sure whenever you use the entity you tell CD not to fault in properties until you ask. You can work around that by isolating the blobs in their own entities, which will not get faulted until you access it through the relationship.
2. Your persistent store is one monolithic file, which means if anything in it changes the whole thing needs to be copied during backups. This often increases the time it takes for the phone to backup while it is synching with iTunes, because you changed some metadata and now it has to copy every image.

   The first issue is usually not a big deal, you just need to be careful. The second is not an issue if the data is effectively readonly, but if you have a couple hundred megabytes of data in your persistent store it can be a pretty awful user experience.

Comment: OK. I have a couple of Gigabytes in my database on my iPad (including 25.000 photo´s) and automatic backup is a pain in the ass. Seems I need to move the photo´s from the Core Data database to a directory that does not get backed up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in:

[Can I access the files used for external binary storage in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222632/can-i-access-the-files-used-for-external-binary-storage-in-core-data/13497992#13497992)

You can store large files in Core Data now using the 'Allows External Storage' option.  The only problem with this is no longer having access to the actual files by path anymore.  I came up with a 'creative' solution (whether it best practice is anyones guess), but it will allow you to use Core Data to manage your files while still being able to access the REAL files by their path.