# How to download audio file from a link and save it to my music gallery?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, download

Anyone can help me how can I download an audio file (mp3) from a link and save it to my music gallery?

Comment: Can you add the code or elaborate what you have tried?

Comment: i have tried to download the file but i can't format it as mp3

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to save audio file to "Music library".
It's only possible when the app will be distributing through Cydia.
But you're going to do, check this out - [libiPodImport](https://github.com/H2CO3/libipodimport)

Comment: how about if i save it to my coredata?

Comment: It is possible to save file to Core Data. However, you can check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114926/iphone-storing-video-and-audio-in-core-data

Answer (score 1):

Just download the song you want from a Youtube to mp3 converter and then place all the songs you want into itunes and move it over.